# identifying the null element in XSLT which has no value even in child elements

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

checking for an Null element

```
<image><a><img src="abcd"/></a></image>
```

XSLT template:

```
<xsl:if test="image!=''">
IMAGE HAS TEXT OR INNER ELEMENT
</xsl:if>
```

I am getting blank output though the "image" element has child elements. and Ideally it is not null.

I have to check the condition that it should have value or the child elements. The child elements can be empty.

How to rectify this.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use**:

```
image[string() or node()]
```

This evaluates to `true()` only if there is at least one `image` child of the current node, such that its string value is non-empty, or it has children (or both).

**This can be simplified just to**:

```
 image[node()]
```

taking into account that in order to have string value, an element must have a text node descendant in its sub-tree.

**If you want the string value of `image` (if any) to be not all-whitespace**, modify the first of the above XPath expressions to:

```
image[normalize-space() or node()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<xsl:if test="image/node()">...</xsl:if>` to check whether the `image` element has any kind of child node or `<xsl:if test="image/*">...</xsl:if>` to test whether the `image` element has at least one child element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to check for any child nodes (text, elements etc)

```
<xsl:template match="image">
    <xsl:if test="node()">
        IMAGE HAS TEXT OR INNER ELEMENT
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Or you can be more specific:

```
<xsl:template match="image">
    <xsl:if test="a | text()">
        IMAGE HAS TEXT OR INNER ELEMENT
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```